# Apply Fermat's little theorem to show that $A ^ { e d } \equiv A ( \bmod p )$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> **Problem** : Let $p$, $q$ two distincts prime numbers and $n=pq$. Let $e$ be a prime number such that $\gcd( (p-1)(q-1),e) = 1$ and $d$ such that  $ed=1+k(p-1)(q-1)$. Let $A \in \mathbb { Z } / n$. 
>   Show that $A ^ { e d } \equiv A \pmod p$.

**My solution** : We have that $ed \equiv 1 (\bmod p-1)$. Thus by Fermat's little theorem:

$A ^ { e d } \equiv A^{k(p-1)+1} \equiv A^{k(p-1)}A^{1} \equiv ({A^{p-1}})^{k}A \stackrel{\text{Fermat}}{\equiv} 1^k A \equiv A  \pmod p$.

**Question** : Does the reasoning seems correct? Am I missing some steps?

Comment: I would only suggest to choose another letter (not $k$) , but besides this : perfect solution.

Comment: @Peter Awesome, thank you very much!